# Bootstrap change button color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am using the script,
which changes the "On" to "Off"

but I also want the button color to change
so "btn-primary" to faded color.

using the "disabled" fades the color but makes the button unclickable.

```
<script>
$('.onbtn, .onbtn').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('onbtn onbtn');
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text == "On" ? "Off" : "On");
});
</script>
```

What would I have to change?

Comment: Try something like $("#btn-primary").css("opacity","0.5");

Comment: Or just create another css class that and toggle that.

Comment: I like the opacity concept, how would I implement the code?
I am not completely fluent in javascript.

<a href="#" class="onbtn btn btn-default btn-info btn-sm">On</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just copied the style of the "disabled button" from bootstrap and edit it for this **new** class "faded".

```
  .faded {
    filter: alpha(opacity=65);
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    opacity: .65;
  }
```

Is **[this](http://www.bootply.com/130448)** how you want it ?